# How to access a parent's binding? Or a better way?

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml, binding, event-handling

```
<toolkit:HubTile Title="{Binding AppName, Converter={StaticResource AddNewLineConvertor}}" Message="{Binding AppDescription}" Source="{Binding AppIconLocation}" GroupTag="featuredAppHubTiles" Margin="0, 0, 20, 20" Tap="featuredAppTapped">
                                <toolkit:ContextMenuService.ContextMenu>
                                    <toolkit:ContextMenu>
                                        <toolkit:MenuItem Header="Share" Tap="ShareFeaturedAppTapped"/>
                                    </toolkit:ContextMenu>
                                </toolkit:ContextMenuService.ContextMenu>
                            </toolkit:HubTile>
```

Hi guys.

In the above code I'm trying to get the name of the application in the `ShareFeaturedAppTapped` event handler, but of course the only item supplied in the event arguments is the `MenuItem`, which doesn't have any property I can really bind the `AppName` to.

How would you go about getting it?

I've tried accessing the parent element (the `HubTile`) but that doesn't seem appropriate.

Thanks,

Danny

Answer (score 0):

```
‎((sender as FrameworkElement).DataCont​ext as MyClass
```

where MyClass is the class for your binding

Comment: As answered previously by Richard Walters

Comment: Hi Dean, welcome to StackOverflow. It's good practice to add a link when referring to other posts - hit the "help" link next to the comments box for explanation of the markdown syntax for adding links, text formatting etc.